# Get forms with # in URL

Tags: html, forms, get

I am trying to get this ***get form*** to take me to a URL based on the users input (search keyword).

```
<form method="get" action="https://rally1.rallydev.com/#/search" target="_blank">
<input type="text" name="keywords" size="25" maxlength="255" value="US111111">
<input type="submit" value="Search"/>
```

In this case, the Value (US111111) is set by default but this is user editable.
When the above query is executed, the following URL **should be** opened

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/#/search?keywords=US111111
```

However, instead

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/?keywords=US144771#/search
```

Is opened.

I think I see why this is happening, the # seems to indicate the root path.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out, but had to use js.

in the html page I used:

```
<input type="text" name="q" id="q" autofocus>
<input type="button" id="s" value="Search">
```

and in the js:

```
$(function() {
    $('#s').click(function() {
        var url  = "https://rally1.rallydev.com/#/3961662024ud/search?keywords=" + $('#q').val();
        chrome.tabs.create({url: url});
    });

    $('#q').keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == '13') {
            e.preventDefault();//Stops the default action for the key pressed
            var url  = "https://rally1.rallydev.com/#/3961662024ud/search?keywords=" + $('#q').val();
            chrome.tabs.create({url: url});
            return false;//extra caution, may not be necessary
        }
    });
});


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded');
```

Hope this helps someone else.